# How to get all possible regex matches in a string

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I am attempting to write a program that will look for series of numbers in a string that could be interpreted as dates. To that end, I have written a regular expression which I run like this:

```
Dim m As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(_string, "[0-9]{1,4}[-_ ]?[0-9]{1,2}([-_ ]?[0-9]{2,4})?")
```

Now, when I give it some weird string like "4_2_2012_13_39", I would expect it to return the following nine matches:

1. 4_2
2. 4_2_20
3. 4_2_2012
4. 2_20
5. 2012
6. 2012_13_39
7. 12_13
8. 12_13_39
9. 13_39

(I have a secondary step that would discard numbers 6 and 9 for not having any number in the range for a month value.) In fact, I get only two matches: "4_20_2012" and "13_39". I think it's trying not to use the same character in two matches. Is there a way that I can insist that it not do so? Thank you for any help.

Rob

Comment: Afaik with .NET regex you can only get one match per starting position in a string. So of for example the results 1 to 3 you could only choose one. (From a single regex run at least.) PS: How is match 6 different from match 3?

Comment: No. By default matches cannot overlap. You could get results 1, 4, 5, 8, 9 (and some others), by calling `Match` in a loop with an offset (incrementing that offset by 1 for each call). But for a single starting position, you will only get one match.

Comment: I have a feeling that to do what you want, regex alone will not be enough. You will have to develop some code logic

Comment: You could do it run independent regex for each date format

Comment: Think of what you're asking. If things worked that way and you wrote `Regex.Matches(_string, ".*")`, with `_string` being 1,000 characters long, you'd end up with a million matches.

Comment: It is good that you include want you have tried.  But you need to clearly define what you want.  What is absolutely problematic is 2_10_2012_2_11.  Do you really want the 2012 used both ways?  In mathematical terms you more degrees of freedom than constraints.

Comment: @Qtax: You are right about match number 6. That was a typo, and I have edited my original post.

Comment: @Jim_Mischel: First, I assume that's not default behavior, but would require the use of an option. Second, why would I do that?

Comment: @Blam: Yes, I really do want 2012 used both ways. I'm trying to find every possible way in which the string could potentially be interpreted as a date; I'll narrow it down later through a combination of logic and user input. It surprises me that having too few constraints makes this more difficult.

Comment: The ".*" was a simple example. It's pretty easy to come up with samples of real expressions that would result in an unexpectedly huge number of matches. True, it could be an option. Or you could do as suggest and just write a loop that starts the regex at each position.

Comment: If you want 2012 both ways then just regex for it both ways.   If you build a separate regex for every date format you want to find then that will work.  Just take the month day I provided and in one add year I provided in the front and in the other the year at the end.

Comment: It seems as though the loop method could result in a lot of duplicate matches. Is there a simple way to get rid of the duplicates?

Comment: Seems?  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want strings that could be interpreted as dates but are not valid dates?  2012_13_39 is not a valid date.

You could run independent regex for each date type

This would look for 4 digit year starting with 19 or 20
The negative look back and look forward is to match on anything not a digit to identify a stand alone number

```
(?<!\d)(20|19)\d\d(?!\d)
```

This is to look for month day

```
(?<!\d)1?\d_[1-3]?\d(?!\d)
```

but you could be even more restrictive as this allows 19/39

Year at beginning

```
(?<!\d)(20|19)\d\d_1?\d_[1-3]?\d(?!\d)
```

I am not going to build them all up for you but this is the tools to do it
(?!\d) should work as a boundary

Answer (score 0):

It will give you the longest match for each start point, not every possible match (just as matching `abcdef` against `.*` will return the match `abcdef`, not all possible substring off it (so not `a` or `f` or `bcd`)